# Add auth headers to swagger

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger

I have added token authentication for my api calls. To run the api from swagger I am unable to add access-token to auth headers, as there was no option for authentication headers. Any idea how can we add it in swagger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `settings.py` file define a `SWAGGER_SETTINGS` dictionary having `api_key` key and its value should be a valid key/token for your api.

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'api_key': 'yourKeyGoesHere',
}
```

you can also specify other configuration settings to be used by swagger. Follow the link for more info: http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/